# How to fake OS bit version check on some software

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, 32-bit, compatibility

I have an application which has detection of my windows version. And it only goes through when it checks that its 32-bit version. As far as I know that my Windows 7 64-bit has compatibility to run 32-bit application, but how can I cheat/fake program to pass that check? :)

Comment: +1, I detest software that refuses to install because of what it *thinks* it is capable of running on. Give me a warning and let me proceed at my own peril. I won't buy HP printers any more because their software wouldn't install on my W2003 Server (among other reasons).

Answer (score 2):

Why would a piece of software care if it's on 64-bits if it's designed for 32? It should work regardless if it's on 64 or 32 bits. Are you sure it's not the Windows version check that fails over being on Windows 7? I've had this for some driver-setups for my Asus motherboard, they claimed to be not compatible with Windows 7, but would work on Vista. Easily solved by setting the compatibility mode for the installer (right click on the program -> properties -> compatibility tab, and choose which windows version it should emulate).

Comment: no no. I am sure of it. The program runs alright! But the first window shows message with something like this: "This Windows OS isn't 32-bit, can't proceed further".

Comment: What kind of software are you trying to install, because not all 32-bits software can run directly on 64 bit (as it turned out I was wrong, you learn some every day). See also: http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-windows7-vista64-support-32bit-applications.htm

It explains why certain 32-bits software won't run under 64-bits OS. If that's the case, then I'm afraid even if there's a way to 'fake' 32 bits, it won't help you.

Comment: +1, especially for the link in the above comment. Interesting stuff.